# Why does a not-backpressure-supportted Observable keep emitting item when it got a Request Notification?

Tags: rx-java

According to Observable Contract,

> An Observable that does not implement backpressure should respond to 
>   a Request notification from an observer by issuing an OnError notification 
>   that indicates that backpressure is not supported.

However, I tried below and it did not notify onError. 
Moreover, it even ignored the request notification.

```
Observable.interval(1L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
      @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        request(1L);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Long t) {
        System.out.println("t=" + t);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("completed");
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
```

I think that observable send an OnError notification when Subscriber send a Request notification to an Observable that does not support backpressure, as the Observable contact said.

Since it does not end up with an OnError notification and developers might believe that a Request notification is working, poorly-tested application might have bugs which were hard to be noticed after product release.

Are there any reasons not to send an OnError notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backpressure in 1.x is half-enforced. Such sources just ignore requests and some other intermediate operators may report MissingBackpressureException if they can't keep up. 2.x is going to be much more strict and sources themselves will signal  onError if they can't emit their values.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! It's glad to know about that and to hear about 2.x. So, are there no reason not to send an OnError notification? For example, to send an OnError notification is ideal but not easy to use since an OnError notification were sent too often.